# EntityFramework Schema specified is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I know this question was already asked but it seams that my case might be slightly different. I tried the "run custom tool" but here's where the strange thing happens: Because i'm having 2 related databases (so 2 related models). If i'm running the custom tool on one model it screws up the other and vice-versa(incomplete .cs files, missing, etc.). Does anyone have any ideea where i'm going wrong?

EDIT:

the complete error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> The relationship
>   'ProductionMasterDataEntityModel.FK_ProductGroup_CostPeriods' was not
>   loaded because the type 'ProductionMasterDataEntityModel.ProductGroup'
>   is not available.
>
> The following information may be useful in resolving the previous
>   error:
>
> The required property 'CstAveOrderQty' does not exist on the type
>   'SISCOM.Persistance.Models.ProductGroup'.

The custom tool is: TextTemplatingFileGenerator

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the asp.net framework but it is an asp.net project so i thought it's worth mentioning.

Comment: What is the tool? What is the error? How it relates to ASP.NET?

Comment: eddited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that i had 2 problems contributing to that error.. First, there were some stored procedures and views, after i got that out of the way (deleted my models, created them again and i've unchecked the option to include the stored procedures and i only added the tables to the model, no views and no stored procedures) i could access some data but not all of it.. The second problem was that i forgot to add a connection to the dependent database.

So the methods in my repository look like this:

```
public myType GetSomething()
{
 var db = new model();
 var dependencyDb = new dependencyModel();
 //do whatever needs to be done with the data before presenting it
 return something;
}
```

P.S... i didn't had to explicitly take it to the needed table, after i added the connection it found all that it needed by itself.

Hope this helps anyone having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, this Issue came after I update .edmx file. Remove all the tables on it and re-update it.right click on .tt file(Eg. Entity.tt) file->Run custom tools. then my issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this case like below.

Entity in class lib project and i was try to consume in other project.
So in that project i have add reference **"EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"** in new project.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the model from edmx and add it again should sort it out. Note this cannot be reverted unless using source control tools.

Comment: cr*p... i accidentally eddited your answer instead of writing a comment, srry... like i said.. can't even track the dependencies since they're really missing from my model even after i rebuilt...

Comment: Never mind, what i would rather do in this scenerio is to drop the model from edmx and add it again that closes most of the changes issues. Take a note that this cant be reverted unless you are using proper source control tools. Do a validate after you add them.